# C# conditional string that fill the "Home Address" if there is not "Temporary Address" and visa-versa. Please

Tags: c#

I have 2 addresses and need to fill one field with one address, if exists, OR another address if it does not

Insert this address:

```
Addresses.Temporary[0].Full_Address_single_line
```

OR IF NOT, enter this address:

```
Addresses.Home_Permanent[0].Full_Address_single_line
```

If the temporary address has no data in the database, the string should input the permanent address.

Comment: What field are you filling? You need to provide more detail about your code. Also, what does "exist" mean to you? Not null? Or do you mean if the street address refers to one of those blank spaces on the map that so exercised Conrad's imagination?

Comment: You want to add the temporary address if existing, otherwise the permanent?

Comment: Hi Ed, thank you for responding. We have multiple addresses in our database and I need an "IF, ELSE" string the will input the "Home_Permanent" address if the "Temporary" address is null

Comment: yes to your second message.

Comment: The 2 strings that I noted above are the 2 identifiable tables that the program is pulling the info from.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [NULL coalesce operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) `??` assuming that "does not exist" means `NULL`:

```
var savedValue = Addresses.Temporary[0].Full_Address_single_line
    ?? Addresses.Home_Permanent[0].Full_Address_single_line;
```

Or if "does not exist" could mean empty string, you could use the `String.IsEmptyOrNull` method with the [ternary operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) `expression ? ifTrue : ifFalse`:

```
var savedValue = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Addresses.Temporary[0].Full_Address_single_line)
    ? Addresses.Temporary[0].Full_Address_single_line
    : Addresses.Home_Permanent[0].Full_Address_single_line;
```

Or you could just use the tried and true `If Else` statement:

```
string savedValue;
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Addresses.Temporary[0].Full_Address_single_line))
{
    savedValue = Addresses.Home_Permanent[0].Full_Address_single_line;
}
else
{
    savedValue = Addresses.Temporary[0].Full_Address_single_line;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `String.IsNullOrWhitespace` to cover other non-existing scenarios.